# Por que se cierra mi modal? bootstrap, javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

por que se oculta mi modal??? Estos son mis botones:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      <button id="btn-agregar-a-tabla" type="button" name="agregar" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Guardar</button>
```

si se presiona el boton agregar, hace un par de validaciones, si es true se oculta perfecto como deberia, pero si la validacion es false, no se deberia de ocultar, deberia de seguir mostrandose el modal para corregir los campos:

```
$('#btn-agregar-a-tabla').click(function() {
    var form2 = $( "#formgrupofamiliar" );
    form2.validate();
    if (form2.valid()) //ACA ESTA LA VALIDACION, EN EL ELSE, NO SE DEBERIA DE ESCONDER
    {
      if($("#datosentabla tr").length <= 5 && bool_au_beca)
      {
        //obtenemos el valor de los input
        nombre = document.getElementById("nombref").value;
        apellido = document.getElementById("apellidof").value;
        vinculo = document.getElementById("vinculo").value;
        fechanacimiento = document.getElementById("fechanacimiento").value;
        telcel = document.getElementById("telcel").value;
        ocupacion = document.getElementById("ocupacion").value;
        ingreso = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
        comentarioingreso = document.getElementById("comentarioingreso").value;
        ttarea2 = document.getElementById("ttarea2").value;
        ttarea3 = document.getElementById("ttarea3").value;
        ttarea4 = document.getElementById("ttarea4").value;
        ttarea5 = document.getElementById("ttarea5").value;
        //validamos que esten con datos....

        // PONER LAS VARIABLES TAREA Y TODAS EN LA VARIABLE FILA PEDASO DE BURRO QUE SOY
        var fila = '<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input name="nombret[]" value="'+nombre+'"></td><td><input name="apellidot[]" value="'+apellido+'"></td><td><button type="button" name="upd_igf" id="upd_'+i+'" class="btn btn-success btn_upd">Editar</button> <button type="button" name="remove" id="del_'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Quitar</button></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="vinculot[]" value="'+vinculo+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="fechanacimientot[]" value="'+fechanacimiento+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="telcelt[]" value="'+telcel+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ocupaciont[]" value="'+ocupacion+'""></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ingresoestimadot[]" value="'+ingreso+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="comentarioingresot[]" value="'+comentarioingreso+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ttarea2t[]" value="'+ttarea2+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ttarea3t[]" value="'+ttarea3+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ttarea4t[]" value="'+ttarea4+'"></td><td style="display:none;"><input name="ttarea5t[]" value="'+ttarea5+'"></td></tr>';

       //esto seria lo que contendria la fila

        i++;

        $('#datosentabla tr:last').after(fila);
        $("#adicionados").text("");

        var nFilas = $("#datosentabla tr").length;
        $("#adicionados").append(nFilas - 1);
        $("#modal").modal('hide');
      }
      else if ($("#datosentabla tr").length <= 5 && !bool_au_beca)
      {

          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='nombret[]']").val(document.getElementById("nombref").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='apellidot[]']").val(document.getElementById("apellidof").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='vinculot[]']").val(document.getElementById("vinculo").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='fechanacimientot[]']").val(document.getElementById("fechanacimiento").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='telcelt[]']").val(document.getElementById("telcel").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='ocupaciont[]']").val(document.getElementById("ocupacion").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='ingresoestimadot[]']").val(document.getElementById("ingreso").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='comentarioingresot[]']").val(document.getElementById("comentarioingreso").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='ttarea2t[]']").val(document.getElementById("ttarea2").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='ttarea3t[]']").val(document.getElementById("ttarea3").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='ttarea4t[]']").val(document.getElementById("ttarea4").value);
          $("#datosentabla").find("tr#row"+ ubic_au_beca).find("input[name='ttarea5t[]']").val(document.getElementById("ttarea5").value);
        bool_au_beca= true;
        $("#modal").modal('hide');
      }
      else
      {
       alert('No se puede agregar mas familiares, número de familiares maximo');
       $("#modal").modal('hide');

      }

      //le resto 1 para no contar la fila del header
      document.getElementById("apellidof").value ="";
      document.getElementById("nombref").value = "";
      //document.getElementById("nombref").focus();
      document.getElementById("vinculo").value = "";
      document.getElementById("fechanacimiento").value = "";
      document.getElementById("telcel").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ocupacion").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ingreso").value = "";
      document.getElementById("comentarioingreso").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ttarea2").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ttarea3").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ttarea4").value = "";
      document.getElementById("ttarea5").value = "";
      document.getElementById("observaciones").value = "";
    }
    else
    {
      alert('Corriga los campos antes de agregar a la tabla');
      $('#modal').modal('show'); //ACA ES DONDE SE ME VA EL MODAL, SE ESCONDE, SE DEBERIA DE SEGUIR MOSTRANDO
    }

  });
```

EDIT: si le saco la propiedad **data-dismiss="modal"** al  boton guardar, Tengo el problema con el **$("#modal").modal('hide');**

EDIT2: Este es mi modal una vez que esta mostrandose:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quita la línea `$("#modal").modal('hide');` al final del `else`, porque eso es lo que hace que se cierre.

Comment: cual de todas ?

Comment: Donde no se tiene que cerrar es en el ultimo ELSE, esta bien identado, si la validacion del formulario es false, tiene que mostrarse, no esconderse, esa propiedad que me decis no esta en dicho ELSE